# Plotting: overlay raster on vector

Tags: python, geopandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to create something like this:

[image: something like this]

Which can be done in R using this guide: https://www.mzes.uni-mannheim.de/socialsciencedatalab/article/geospatial-data/

While I enjoy R I would like to know how to plot/overlay multiple rasters on top of a vector basemap in Python, using opacity. The only StackOverflow questions I could find were about patching rasters with vectors which I believe is the opposite of the above image.

Here is the code I have so far:

```py
import rasterio as rio
import pyrosm
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib as mpl
import geopandas as gpd
import earthpy.spatial as es
import earthpy.plot as ep
import earthpy as et
import contextily as ctx
from shapely.geometry import Point
from rasterio.windows import from_bounds
from rasterio.plot import show_hist
from rasterio.plot import show
from rasterio.plot import plotting_extent
from rasterio.mask import mask
import better_exceptions

def add_basemap(ax, zoom):
    xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = ax.axis()
    basemap, extent = ctx.bounds2img(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, zoom=zoom, source=ctx.providers.Stamen.Toner)
    ax.imshow(basemap, extent=extent, interpolation='bilinear')
    # restore original x/y limits
    ax.axis((xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax))

src = rio.open('abandoned_cog2.tif')

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'LAT'  :[-22.266415],
    'LONG' :[166.452764],
})
df['coords'] = list(zip(df.LONG, df.LAT))

# ... turn them into geodataframe, and convert our
# epsg into 3857, since web map tiles are typically
# provided as such.
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df, crs  = 'epsg:4326', geometry = df['coords'].apply(Point)
).to_crs(epsg=3857).buffer(8000)

masked, affine, win = rio.mask.raster_geometry_mask(src, geo_df, crop=True)
rst = src.read(1, window=win)

ax = geo_df.plot(figsize= (8, 8), alpha  = 0)
add_basemap(ax, zoom=13)

# im = ax.imshow(rst, cmap=cm.jet, interpolation='none', clim=[0.01, 1])

show(rst, cmap="viridis", ax=ax)
```

One weird thing that I noticed is that when I run

show(rst, cmap='summer')

It shows the raster but when adding ax=ax the basemap isn't changed

[image]

oh I guess when I read with window it doesn't remember the location. How can I copy the location so it is plotted correctly? Is there a better way to do this? It seems like reading from window is very fast so that is why I did it

[image]

I think I'm getting closer?? If I use plotting_extent and set clim 0,1 then I get BSOD :o

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay it works like this

`show(rst, ax=ax, extent=plotting_extent(rst, affine), cmap=cm.jet, clim=[0.01, 1])`

[image]

Comment: You should accept your answer